# Последовательность отображения компонентов

Tags: html, typescript, angular, angular-routing, angular-ui-router

У меня есть 2 компонента. `Registration component` и `main component`. Как мне в браузере отобразить `register component`? После регистрации отобразить `main component`? То-есть, когда человек открывает ссылку на сайт, у него сперва высветится `registration component`, затем после регистрации, и если она успешна, пользователю высветится `main component`. Я попытался отобразить `registration component` в `app.module.ts`:

```
RouterModule.forRoot ([
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'registration', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'registration', component: RegisterComponent }
])
```

Мне просто нужно первым отобразить `registration component`, я начинающий и вообще не знаю как отображать компоненты.

Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно быть наоборот (обычно идем от специфического к общему) и не забываем слэш при редиректе:

```
RouterModule.forRoot ([  
  { path: 'registration', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/registration', pathMatch: 'full' },
])
```

Теперь, при вводе в адресной строке `http<s>://<имя домена>` мы попадаем на `path: ''` и далее мы переходим по редиректу на регистрацию.

[док](https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-redirects)

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое! А не подскажите как мне после регистрации вывести main компонент?Вот так: `{ path: 'registration', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/registration', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'main', component: MainComponent },`

Comment: Или вот так? `{path: 'main', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [RegisteredGuard]}`

Comment: @DanyloKobzar конечно второе - вы должны прописать рут до мейна и есть надо, то проверять зареган пользователь или нет, а в коде, после регистации сделать navigate. Короче вот https://stackoverflow.com/a/47134257/4711135

Comment: Понял, вопросов больше нет, спасибо большое.